# Can I clear headers that sent? on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, header

For example

```
 Response.Write("<div id='divTitle'>Loading</div>");
 Response.Flush();
 ....
 ....
 Response.Redirect("home.aspx", false);
```

I got the following error:

> `Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.`

Please help.

Comment: You can't. After you've called `Response.Flush` - your server have sent data to client, so you can't "recall" it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the message is clear. You sent headers with `Response.Flush();`. You are trying both  to send content and redirect request. Why?

**UPDATE:**

```
Response.Buffer =false;
Response.Write("<div id='divTitle'>Loading</div>");
Response.Flush();

// do something

Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.location = 'home.aspx' </script>");
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: This page is loading page for the client and make work on server
when the work on server is done I want to 
Response.Redirect automatic to home.

Comment: So just redirect when the work is done, his question still stands: why you trying to do both?

Comment: How can I tell the user "wait please" and than redirect when the job is done?